# Find element closest to click coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there an easy way to detect the closest child element to the coordinates of a mouse click in the container?. In this case the container is a div

Ex:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">
  <span>E1</span>
  <span>\n</span>
  <span>\n</span>
  <span>E4</span>
  <span>E5</span>
</div>
```

In the above case I would like to determine the span with the closest top/left coordinates to where the click took place in the div. Due to line breaks the spans don't fully cover the div

In my click event I have access to top/left through e.clientY;

However, I am having some difficulty traversing the spans to detect which span is closest to the coordinates of the click inside the div.

click handler:

```
function(e){
 var yop = e.clientY;
}
```

Comment: No, there is not an easy way to do this, you'll have to check the position of every element on the page for each click.

Comment: Well, not every element. He can add a click handler to the document itself and then only has to check the child elements of the element from which the click event originated.

Comment: Interesting question. Yes, using jQuery's `each` on the children of the clicked element and calculating the distance for each one is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that might be useful about `document.elementFromPoint`:

From the summary on the MDN link:

> Returns the element from the document whose elementFromPoint method is
>   being called which is the topmost element which lies under the given
>   point.  To get an element, specify the point via coordinates, in CSS
>   pixels, relative to the upper-left-most point in the window or frame
>   containing the document.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint

So in a nutshell, it drops a pin down the z-index stack at an `x, y` coordinate, and returns the first element it hits. Super useful, though per the Quirksmode page its support is limited.